# How to modify Docker container configuration of Azure?

Tags: azure, docker

These pics show my process of deployments on Azure Docker with Eclipse IDE.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The problem is I have no idea how to modify Wildfly Docker configuration. For example, Datasource JNDI and undertow setting of Wildfly AS in Docker container.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the Docker container as follows:

**Predefined Docker image:** Specifies a pre-existing Docker image from Azure.
[!NOTE] The list of Docker images in this box consists of several images that the Azure Toolkit has been configured to patch so that your artifact is deployed automatically.

**Custom Dockerfile:** Specifies a previously saved Dockerfile from your local computer.
[!NOTE] This is a more advanced feature for developers who want to deploy their own Dockerfile. However, it is up to developers who use this option to ensure that their Dockerfile is built correctly. The Azure Toolkit does not validate the content in a custom Dockerfile, so the deployment might fail if the Dockerfile has issues. In addition, the Azure Toolkit expects the custom Dockerfile to contain a web app artifact, and it will attempt to open an HTTP connection. If developers publish a different type of artifact, they may receive innocuous errors after deployment.

For more details, refer https://github.com/Azure/azure-docs-sdk-java/blob/master/docs-ref-conceptual/eclipse/azure-toolkit-for-eclipse-publish-as-docker-container.md.